# waiting for boolean in json file to change in loop

Tags: node.js

I have another node program to set the loop value in the config file, however even if the loop value changes in the file the loop just doesn't see it so i'm stumped

```
while (true) {
    if(require('./config.json').loop) {
    moveMouse();
    console.log('looped');
  } else continue;
}
```

Comment: What actually changes the `.loop` property in the JSON file?  If it's code in this same node.js process, then this will never happen because `while(true)` blocks and never lets anything else run.  Also `require()` caches modules so you are always getting the same cached config.json everytime.  You could use `fs.readFile()` and then `JSON.parse()`, but you would still have the blocking loop issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because require cache the module.
It's better to use read file and not use require for reading files.

If you still want to use require you still can delete the cache before the next require :

```
while (true) {
    // delete cached module before require again
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./config.json')]
    if(require('./config.json').loop) {
       moveMouse();
       console.log('looped');
      } else continue;
}
```

Comment: Note: this will "hang" the node.js process until it finds the `.loop` property has changed to to true because the `while` loop is blocking and the event loop is not given a chance to do anything else.

Comment: Yes that is true. Never use the while(true) in production.

Comment: Unless it's in an `async` function and you're using `await`.  That's the one place that `while(true)` can occasionally be OK.  Also, if this is browser code which the `moveMouse()` kind of implies, then this will hang the browser too.

Comment: this appeared to give `config.json: Unexpected end of JSON input` as soon as the loop variable was changed to true

Comment: Validate your json after the variable change. You can use any tool in google. or you can share the json with us.

Comment: to me it looks fine and a json validator says its fine, the error occurs when it tries to require the config file

Comment: Try to require the file with initial value loop : true. Do you still get the same error ? How are you changing the json ?

Comment: to change the json im just using another node program which uses fs.writeFile to change the file also im not quite sure what you mean by that

Comment: Try to change  config.json manually, i believe you will not get the error. Thats because when you write(in second node program) and read the json(in first node program) at the same time the json will be broken and you will get the error ! You can add try catch when you require the config.json and inside the catch do nothing. so your process wont exit with error and continue another attempts until you finish writeFile in your second node process. Hope this answer you.

Comment: interestingly enough editing it manually still caused the program to error but the try catch fixed it so tysm

Answer (score 0):

How about using node's watchFile?

**watcher.js**

```
const  { watchFile, readFile, readFileSync } = require('fs')

const file = readFileSync('./config.json')
const originalConfig = JSON.parse(file.toString())

let prevValue = originalConfig.value

watchFile('./config.json', (curr, prev) => {
  const currTime = new Date(curr.mtime).getTime()
  const prevTime = new Date(prev.mtime).getTime()

  const hasChanged = currTime !== prevTime
  
  if (hasChanged) {
    readFile('./config.json', (err, data) => {
      const config = JSON.parse(data.toString())
      const value = config.value
      
      console.log('value was:', prevValue)
      console.log('value is now', value)

      prevValue = value
    })
  }
})
```

**config.json**

```
{
  "value": false
}
```

Here the code

1. reads the config.json
2. parses it as a json
3. Reads the property 'value' which has a boolean value
4. Watches the file
5. When the timestamp have changed, we know somebody modified the json file
6. We read the file again (since it has changed)
7. Parse it and read the values